# How can I flag (follow) user by REST API using service resources?

Tags: services, flags, 8

I am using flag module to have the following user function. So that the followers will be able to read the blog of the users that they followed.
Now I want to provide api for mobile application, when a userA go to profile of userB, they can follow userB by follow button. Is there any way to return an api by POST method in RESTfull to do like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

**Flag**

```
URL: http://example.com/apiauthd/flag/flag

Method: POST

Parameters:-
    flag_name: like
    action: flag
    uid: { uid of the logged in user}
    entity_id: { uid of the other user to be flagged}
```

**Unflag**

```
URL: http://example.com/apiauthd/flag/flag

Method: POST

Parameters:-
    flag_name: like
    action: unflag
    uid: { uid of the logged in user}
    entity_id: { uid of the other user to be unflagged}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how to integrate it with hook service resources?

Comment: You dont have to integrate it with hook service resources for flag service to work.

Comment: Could you explain more? How can I add api for flagging to endpoint?

Comment: I think I understand your answer already, thank you for supporting.

Comment: I'm trying this with Drupal 8 Rest api (/entity/flagging) and nearly there, posting this: {
  "entity_id":[{"target_id":34}],
  "flag_id": "my flag type",
  "uid": [{"target_id": 1 }],
  "action": "flag"
}  I get InvalidArgumentException: Field action is unknown.  Any thoughts? Just want to set a flag for an entity for one user.